# How do you pass multiple parameters in java?

Tags: java, variables, parameters

I am a beginner at java and just need to find out how to send multiple parameters to one method (being 'game()'). The program is not complete I just need to get that bit working before I continue. The program is a 'safe-cracker' which takes user input and tells them if there guess is correct or not (I haven't done that part of the code yet). The code needed a menu system where the user can input the original number manually, whether they want hints or not, the amount of guesses they get, and a 3 digit number randomly generated. Any help would be appreciated

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class ModularSafecracker
{
Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void menu()           //main menu
    {
        ModularSafecracker MS = new ModularSafecracker();
        System.out.println("-=-            MENU              -=-");
        System.out.println("1 - Manually set a 3-digit code");
        System.out.println("2 - Randomly generate a 3-digit code");
        System.out.println("3 - Set max number of guesses");
        System.out.println("4 - Turn hints on/off");
        System.out.println("5 - Begin game");
        System.out.println("-=-                              -=-");

        int menuDecision = inputScanner.nextInt();

        if(menuDecision == 1)
        {
            MS.manual();
        }
        if(menuDecision == 2)
        {
            MS.random();
        }
        if(menuDecision == 3)
        {
            MS.setMax();
        }
        if(menuDecision == 4)
        {
            MS.setHints();
        }
        if(menuDecision == 5)
        {
        }

    }

    public void manual()      //option 1
    {
        ModularSafecracker MS = new ModularSafecracker();
        System.out.println("Please enter a 3 digit code");
        int manualCode = inputScanner.nextInt();

        MS.menu();
    }

    public void random()        //option 2
    {
        ModularSafecracker MS = new ModularSafecracker();
        Random x = new Random();
        int randomCode = x.nextInt(899)+100;

        MS.menu();
    }

    public void setMax()     //option 3
    {
        ModularSafecracker MS = new ModularSafecracker();
        System.out.println("Please enter the max number of guesses");
        int max = inputScanner.nextInt();

        MS.menu();
    }

    public void setHints()       //option 4
    {
        ModularSafecracker MS = new ModularSafecracker();
        System.out.println("Would you like hints?");
        String option = inputScanner.nextLine();
        if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));
        {
            int hints = 1;
        }
        if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("No"));
        {
            int hints = 0;
        }

        MS.menu();
    }

    public void game()
    {
        //in this method I want the variables 'max' 'hints' 'manualCode' and 'randomCode'
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ModularSafecracker MS = new ModularSafecracker();
        MS.menu();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Seems that's a question about java basis.. You should store user answers in class fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void game(int max, int hints, int manualCode, int randomCode){
```

You should probably be using boolean for your hints value, and ideally enums for your manualCode and randomCode variables but I went with what you were using

I'd encourage you to read a bit on the very basics, as having a solid foundation will make it much easier for you to teach yourself in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To have the variables 'max', 'hints', 'manualCode' and 'randomCode' in your game method, you need to declare them as instance variables. Right now you have them as local variables for the other methods.

You can read about variables in Java here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html